# Apex Query does not bring data

Tags: apex, query

Hello I have an apex method that uses this query that receives an String with the Id.

```
public static List<WrapperToLWC> getList(String namee){
Id cleanId = (Id) namee;
List<SObject> membersList = new List<SObject>();
membersList = [SELECT Id, SObject1, Rol, SObject2, SObject2.Name, SObject2.Phone, SObject2.Email FROM SObject WHERE SObject1 =: cleanId ];
List<WrapperToLWC> listToLWC = new List<WrapperToLWC>();
if(membersList.isEmpty()){
        listToLWC = null;
        System.debug('No data');
        return listToLWC;
    }else{
System.debug(' I have data');
for(SObject iMiembro: membersList){
    WrapperToLWC iMember = new WrapperToLWC();
    iMember.idCuenta = iMiembro.SObject2;
    iMember.idMember = iMiembro.Id;
    iMember.Name = iMiembro.SObject2.Name;
    iMember.email = iMiembro.SObject2.Email;
    iMember.phone = iMiembro.SObject2.Phone;
    iMember.rol = iMiembro.Rol;
    listToLWC.add(iMember);
}
}
System.debug('list '+ listToLWC);
return listToLWC;
}


public class WrapperToLWC{
@AuraEnabled public String idAccount{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public String Name{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public String email{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public String phone{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public String idMember{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled public String rol{get;set;}
}
```

The problem is that it does not bring me any data but when I go to the Salesforce Inspector I use the same query with the Id the user inserted and the Inspector brings me data.

I need the fields from the object2 to save them in a wrapper that contains data from the principal query and the nested one.
Is my query wrong? What is the problem? Could anybody see or correct it?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of [sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) are you using for your apex controller? second, I would recommend adding a debug statement for `cleanId` variable, just to make sure it has the value you are expecting. and lastly, are you getting any exception?

Comment: @McCubo hello, what do you mean by 'what kind of sharing am I using'. Yeah I have debugs to see what parameter the method receives and I also checked it with the Id in the system. And I am not getting any exception. The debug gives me the 'No data' and the size of the list is 0

Comment: you can use either one of [the following keywords for your apex class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm): `with sharing` or `without sharing`. they determine whether sharing rules must be enforced or not.

Comment: @McCubo oh okay I got it. I had added 'with sharing' and not works

Comment: try using `without sharing` just to make sure it is not a data access issue.