# Nested Query for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, query, wrapper-class, nested, subquery

```
public static List<WrapperToLWC> getList(String namee){
  Id cleanId = (Id) namee;
  List<SObject> membersList = new List<SObject>();
  membersList = [SELECT Id, SObject1, Rol, SObject2, SObject2.Name, SObject2.Phone, 
  SObject2.Email FROM SObject WHERE SObject1 =: cleanId ];
  List<WrapperToLWC> listToLWC = new List<WrapperToLWC>();

  for(SObject iMiembro: membersList){
        WrapperToLWC iMember = new WrapperToLWC();
        iMember.idCuenta = iMiembro.SObject2;
        iMember.idMember = iMiembro.Id;
        iMember.Name = iMiembro.SObject2.Name;
        iMember.email = iMiembro.SObject2.Email;
         iMember.phone = iMiembro.SObject2.Phone;
        iMember.rol = iMiembro.Rol;
        listToLWC.add(iMember);
      }
     System.debug('list '+ listToLWC);
     return listToLWC;
  }


  public class WrapperToLWC{
      @AuraEnabled public String idAccount{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String Name{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String email{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String phone{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String idMember{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String rol{get;set;}
   }
```

The problem is that it does not bring me any data but when I go to the Salesforce Inspector I use the same query with the Id the user inserted and the Inspector brings me data.

I need the fields from the object2 to save them in a wrapper that contains data from the principal query and the nested one. Is my query wrong? What is the problem? Could anybody see or correct it?

Comment: is `getList` method annotated with `@AuraEnabled` annotation?

Comment: Please do not [duplicate question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/395279/apex-query-does-not-bring-data)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is with your wrapper. Try adding a setter method to the wrapper class, passing in your variables. Should work just fine after that. Also you should return all of your data as serialized JSON and do whatever you want with it on the other end.